# WakeLock is getting install on Pod install

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am facing an issue while archiving the build. it gives 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found for wakelock. But not mentioned wakelock flutter plugin in pubspecs.yaml file, but when runnig cammand for POD install it gets installed.

Answer (score 0):

One of your packages you used in pubspecs.yaml, uses wakelock as a dependency,
you can open [wakelock page on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock), and click on "Pacakges that depened on wakelock", then you can see all of packages that using wakelock as a dependency, you maybe have included one of these packages in your pubspecs.yaml

[image: no desc]